# Codeigniter, Message: Undefined variable: params Filename: libraries/tmdb.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem when load a libraries with array `$params`

**=> file libraries** 'libraries/tmdb.php'

```
public function movie_similar($id, $page = 1, $language = NULL, $append = NULL)
{
    $params = array(
        'page'          => $page,
        'language'      => $language,
        'append_to_response'    => $params
    );

    return $this->_call('movie/' . $id . '/similar_movies', $params);
}
```

**=> file controller** 'controller/Movie.php'

```
public function id($id)
{
    if((int)$id > 0){
        $id = $this->uri->segment('3');
        $data['similar'] = $this->tmdb->movie_similar($id,$page=1);
        $this->load->view('movie_view',$data);
    }


}
```

And I have errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: params
Filename: libraries/tmdb.php
Line Number: 172
```

**Backtrace:**

```
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\master\application\libraries\tmdb.php
Line: 172
Function: _error_handler
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\master\application\controllers\Movie.php
Line: 113
Function: movie_similar
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\master\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

how to fix my problem ?

Comment: "File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php"

Comment: refer this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class_and_method_naming styling guide

**it's not necessary for controller or model file name to be in capital[class name must] but in libraries  File names must be capitalized. For example: this.php
Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: class this.php
Class names and file names must match.**

Comment: @vix3r Also, your segment should be integer, not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'append_to_response'    => $prams` i think here `$prams` should be `$append`

```
public function movie_similar($id, $page = 1, $language = NULL, $append = NULL)
{
    $params = array(
        'page'          => $page,
        'language'      => $language,
        'append_to_response'    => $append //this should be $append
    );

    return $this->_call('movie/' . $id . '/similar_movies', $params);
}
```